# Will JS-Uglify make it load faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-cli, uglifyjs

What I was trying to do is to make my ember app load faster, the `index.html` file looks like this

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Jobber</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

    {{content-for "head"}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/custom.css">

    {{content-for "head-footer"}}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{content-for "body"}}

    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/custom.js"></script>

    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
  </body>
</html>
```

The size of `vendor.js` and `custom.js` together before uglify is 11mb, after uglify from ember-cli is about 4mb.

Then I tried to profile it in chrome Timeline(5x CPU throttling) to see if there is a noticeable difference. And here is what I got, top 3 charts are summaries after being uglified, bottom 3 are without uglify.

[image: Screen shot]

My question is will uglify really make it load faster? The only difference I can tell is the time spent in category `Other` is less, the `Scripting` part is very close and sometimes even longer.

I did a closer look into the time segmentations, seems like the compile time have decreased a lot but in total there is no much difference, if it does save time, where is the time being saved?

Comment: When you'r using ember-cli the difference between `ember build --dev` and `ember build --prod` is much more then just uglify. Ember does also strip out debug related code.

Comment: Also, are you serving the site locally or are you testing from a server somewhere else?